# Read file into two dimensional list

Tags: python

I would like to read a file of (say 5 rows and 3 columns) into a two dimensional list.
So, here is my code so far:

Say my data file is:

```
 1.0 2.1 3.4
 1.1 2.5 3.0
 2.1 2.4 2.8
 2.6 2.5 5.6
 1.8 8.3 5.4



fil = open('data.dat','r')


data = [[]]         # initialize two-dim. list

for rows in fil:
     cols = rows.split()
     data.append(cols[i] for i in cols)

print(data[:][1])
```

so I expect the command `print(data[:][1])` to print all rows for column 2. That is, the output should be:

```
2.1
2.5
2.4
2.5
8.3
```

Any ideas and help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does it need to be a list? I suggest using numpy.array or Matrix.

Comment: There is a difference between a two-dimensional list (which Python does not support) and a nested list. `data[:]` simply creates a copy of `data`, so `data[:][1]` returns the same value as `data[1]`, rather than accessing element 1 of each row in `data`.

Comment: simply use the python package csv, and then doing **file  = open('data.dat', "rb")** and **data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')**

Answer (score 3):

Since your file is full of numbers, I'd suggest using [`numpy`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NumPy):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> f = open("data.dat")
>>> data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=" ")
>>> data
array([[ 1. ,  2.1,  3.4],
       [ 1.1,  2.5,  3. ],
       [ 2.1,  2.4,  2.8],
       [ 2.6,  2.5,  5.6],
       [ 1.8,  8.3,  5.4]])
```

This way, you can also easily select individual columns from the data:

```
>>> data[:,1]
array([ 2.1,  2.5,  2.4,  2.5,  8.3])
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Problem 1: Filling `data`

You add a generator yielding the columns for each row to data. This means your `data` looks like

```
[[], <generator>, <generator>, ...]
```

What you want to do is start off with an empty list and add the columns for each row:

```
data = []
for row in fil:
    cols = row.split()
    data.append(cols)
```

#### Problem 2: Printing `data`

`data[:][1]` does not do what you expect. It takes all elements from `data` (i.e. it copies the list) and selects the second element. Instead, use

```
[row[1] for row in data]
```

to get the second column of each row. To get the output formatted as you want, you could use `string.join`:

```
print("\n".join(row[1] for row in data))
```

Comment: I am coming from a Fortran background and with two nested loops I can read a file in a two dimensional array (regardless of the type of the elements). I get it that fortran and python are different! 

I am not a huge fan of the ".readlines()" as I am dealing with files of 20GB. I don't see a reason to read the entire file with ".readlines". Out of those billions of lines (say I need only 100). So therefore I was looking hoping that Python would help to read those 100 lines and 30 columns in a two dimensional list of mixed type elements.

Comment: I guess I need to change my "Fortran" logic to "Python" one :))))

Answer (score 0):

Just append each row's datapoints to data.  No need to initialize a list inside of `data`.  Then to get the columnn you want, you can use a list comprehension:

```
fil = open('data.dat','r')


data = []

for rows in fil:
    data.append(rows.split())

print([x[1] for x in data])
```

Comment: Thanks all for your suggestions and help!